# Flask sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and I am trying to add a User to my database. Everything was working fine but (maybe, maybe not) when I upgraded my database I now get the following error message

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a 
previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue 
Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users
```

Anyone know what I can do from here?

here is my models.py:

```
from server import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
from datetime import datetime


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
```

My server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify, redirect, url_for, flash, render_template, 
session, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
#from models import db

app = Flask(__name__)
#app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Welcome!!!"
```

My manage.py

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from server import app, db


#app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I have a config.py file on top but I dont think its relevant here.

So for example when I type 'python manage.py shell' into my terminal and i do something like

```
from models import User, db
db.create_all()
user_susan = User(username='susan', email='susan@hotmail.com')
db.session.add(user_susan)
db.session()
```

That is when the error message populates, which it wasnt before ...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

as the error message said: there was an error with a previous commit on your database (for example: user already exists leads to "unique constraint failed".

[SqlAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/sessions.html) suggests to handle failed commits:

```
try:
    <use session>
    session.commit()
except:
   session.rollback()
   raise <-- you can inspect your root error, if you log/print this exception
finally:
   session.close()  # optional, depends on use case
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which Exceptions from `sqlalchemy.exc` you were catching before.  Newer versions of sqlalchemy can throw differently named Exceptions from earlier versions.

I recently had to switch from catching `sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError` to catching `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError` instead.